# Split loop into columns

Tags: loop, columns

I'm trying to split my loop into 4 columns. 
My logic is very flawed here and my layout is breaking.
Such a simple problem, but I'm struggling with it.

I essentially need each group of four posts to be wrapped in a container "row" div.
And, of course, whatever remaining posts are left over, even if less than four, to be wrapped as well.

```
<div class="twelve columns">    
    <?php 
     $i = 0; 
     if (have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        if ($i == 0) { echo '<div class="row">'; }
        if ($i%4== 0) { echo '</div><div class="row">'; } ?>

        <div class="three columns">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>

        <?php 
         if ( $i%4 == 0) { 
           echo '</div>'; 
         } 
         $i++; 

        endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>
```

I posted this over at stackoverflow as well, but no replies. Any suggestions to solve my problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="all-posts">
   <div class="post-group>
      <?php $i = 0;
      if (have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
         if ($i%4 == 0) echo '</div><div class="post-group">'; ?>
         <div class="post">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
         </div>
         <?php $i++;
      endwhile; endif; ?>
   </div><!-- end post-group -->
</div><!-- end all-posts -->
```

You code was closing, opening and closing div on multiples of 4.
Anyway, I'm guessing all this is about layout, so you should be able to find a better solution only with CSS.

Comment: Badabing...that's it. Thanks! 
So obvious actually...sigh... ;-)